# Metatags trimmed body in description/summary

Tags: 7, tokens, meta-tags

I am using the [Metatag Module](https://drupal.org/project/metatag). Everything works as expected, till I checked the description for each node and saw that it is empty.

Since there is no output with [node:summary] I changed it to [node:body] which works, but now the whole node is in the description field... I checked the available tokens [*:summary, *:value, *:format] with no success.

Any suggestions how to use the [node:body] in a trimmed version?

Comment: If you add another field, like field_excerpt, can you use it with metatag? if so I might know a way for you.

Comment: @Mołot well, that would work. But my customer does not want to fill in "additional" content/work. So I wanted to do it automatically with the existing node body content

Comment: Well, you don't always need to *fill* additional fields ;) I just needed to make sure you can use them at all. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any field with Metatag, so simplest way would be to use [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field), that

> lets you add a custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw on anything available to Drupal, including other fields

In your custom php code for field computation, use code like this:

```
$body = $entity->body['und'][0]['value'];
$width = 160;
$body_trimmed = substr($body, 0, strpos(wordwrap($body, $width), "\n"));
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $body_trimmed;
```

It will truncate on the word boundary, giving you no more than `$width` characters. More about truncating [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79960/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-word-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-chara).

Then, simply feed this computed field to Metatag.

Comment: would you add (as for the computed field settings):

`$body = $entity->body['und'][0]['value'];
$width = 160;
$body_trimmed = substr($body, 0, strpos(wordwrap($body, $width), "\n"));
$entity_field[0]['value'] =$body_trimmed;`

to make it complete?

Comment: @wucherpfennig code updated. Thanks :) And be sure to read SO question I linked, there are some useful hints how to trim safely.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Molot!

I was looking for a way to put a trimmed description field into another field called summary. You would think Drupal would do this automatically but the summary field is only populated if a user enters it manually.

My code looked like this:

```
$desc = $entity->field_prj_desc['und'][0]['value'];
$width = 140;
$desc_trimmed = substr($desc, 0, $width);
$entity_field[0]['value'] =  $desc_trimmed;
```